# Why is there no conjunction in “...symptoms are so slight you do not even know..”?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, conjunctions

I have just finished some of my exercises and this sentence really make me confused:

> Sometimes the symptoms are **so slight you** do not even know you have an allergy, and it may take years for an allergy to become noticeable.

I don't understand why there wasn't any **conjunction** between two clauses: 'Sometimes the symptoms are so slight' and 'you do not even know you have an allergy'.

Could anyone explain it to me, please?

Comment: Please do not use all caps and please visit the help section to see how to ask a question in this forum. Thank you. [x confuses you, it does not "make you confused"] https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a conjunction; it's just that it's been omitted—but still understood to exist:

> Sometimes the symptoms are so slight <sup>[that]</sup> you do not even know you have an allergy.

It's common to omit the use of *that* in many constructions. Idiomatically, the two parts of the sentence are understood to have the relationship between each other made explicit by *that*.

In fact, some people adhere to the style of deliberately omitting *that* for the purpose of eliminating words that aren't essential for easy comprehension.

Why English speakers have all come to easily (in most cases) understand sentences without the use of *that* in particular is not something I could readily explain. Unfortunately, it may be another quirk of English that makes it more difficult for those learning the language.